# Is multiplying by an elementary matrix same as a row operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose I have a matrix $A$ and I perform a row operation on it. Say the elementary matrix from the row operation is $E$ and the new matrix is $B$

Then is it true that

> $B = EA$

Why?